# Writing Head section with PHP

Tags: php, html, include

I'm converting a couple sites from HTML to PHP for dynamic elements and have been able to do so with the header and footer (using php include()). However, I'm confused on how to do the head section. This is what I have with plain HTML:

```
<head>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
  </script>
  <![endif]-->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Liberty Resource Directory. The ultimate curated directory to find what you need."/>
  <meta name="keywords" content="ethan glover, lrd, liberty resource directory"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link href="stylesheets/lrdstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <title>Liberty Resource Directory</title>
</head>
```

I can easily add the HTML5Shim script, meta charset, viewport (yes I will remove that max scale), and the stylesheet link.

**Here's the problem:**

How can I write the .php file in a way that I can pass an individual pages description, keywords and title to it? (That way I can put the entire above code in a php file and just include it on every page.)

Or will I simply have to exclude the description, keywords and title, and rewrite those parts every time?

**Here's the answer:** (Courtesy of Alejandro Arbiza)

head.php

```
<head>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
  </script>
  <![endif]-->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description;?>"/>
  <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords;?>"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="../stylesheets/lrdstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
```

index.html (to include above code)

```
<?php
    $description="Liberty Resource Directory. The ultimate curated directory to find what you need.";
    $keywords="ethan glover, lrd, liberty resource directory";
    $title="Liberty Resource Directory";
    include 'scripts/head.php';
?>
```

The final result:

http://libertyresourcedirectory.com/

Comment: You can use include inside `<head><?php include 'file.php'; ?></head>` - As for an individual page description etc., will require a bit more coding, *I'm afraid*. Use a framework instead; it'll be easier.

Comment: Post your php code. Are you using any framework or bare bones php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables for the description and the keywords (or anything else you want for that matter). Then, when the time comes to construct the page, you would just set the variables with the corresponding values.

```
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link href="stylesheets/lrdstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <title>Liberty Resource Directory</title>
</head>
```

So, lets say you have page1.php and page2.php:

```
<?php
// page1.php
$description = "This is page one";
$keywords = "page one";
include 'header.php';
?>

<!-- Page content --> 

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

and

```
<?php
// page2.php
$description = "This is page two";
$keywords = "page two";
include 'header.php';
?>

<!-- Page content --> 

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Of course, I am assuming here that the whole HTML header is inside the `header.php` file, that is including `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>`.

Comment: Awesome! And of course, you can use PHP inside the page content as well, the same way it's done in the <meta> tags.